# Where are the log files located in the Graylog server Docker container?

Tags: docker, graylog

I'm using the graylog server image from docker [hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/server/) but I can't find the log files. In the graylog [vm](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/installation/virtual_machine_appliances.html) they're located under `/var/log/graylog` but the location doesn't exist in the graylog server docker image. Where are the log files located in the docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`graylog2/server`](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog2/server/) Docker image sends logs to stdout and doesn't write them into a log file.

You can use a [Docker Logging Driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) to configure where these logs should be written to.

Comment: Thanks, using the syslog driver to look at the logs. Added this to docker compose:

Comment: logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:514"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like log4j is configured only to stdout. Inspecting the Dockerfile I would suggest checking this directory:

```
/usr/share/graylog/data/log
```

Also check:

```
/usr/share/graylog/data/journal
```

Regards